# script SQL equivalent

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sqlite

I have this SQLite script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ACCOUNT_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL AFTER UPDATE OF DELETE_SESSION_ID ON ACCOUNT
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN OLD.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL AND NEW.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL
BEGIN
DELETE FROM REFRDEL WHERE PK1 = CAST(OLD.ACCT_ID AS TEXT) AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT';
END;
```

I need an equivalent script for MS SQL Server. I'm learning C# and I'm converting everything through regex, but first I need the correct script. I don't know much about SQL.

I tried this as an equivalent code, but it gives me an error:

> SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.
> Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.
> Invalid column name 'ACCT_ID'.

They helped me with the equivalence:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYACC_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL
ON ACCOUNT
AFTER UPDATE
ACE
BEGIN
  IF UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID)
    BEGIN
      DELETE
      FROM REFRDEL
      WHERE PK1 = CAST(OLD.ACCT_ID AS VARCHAR(50))
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT'
      AND OLD.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL
      AND NEW.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL;
     END;
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server's triggers work very differently than SQLite. **They operate per statement not per row.**

So you need to join the `inserted` and `deleted` (by primary key) and join that to `REFRDEL` to do the delete. Do *not* assume that there will be exactly one row in `inserted` and `deleted`, there may be zero or multiple.

The `UPDATE` function will tell you if the column was present in the update *statement* and can be used for early bailout, it does *not* tell you if any rows were actually changed.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ACCOUNT_UPDATE_DELETE_SESSION_ID_NULL ON ACCOUNT
AFTER UPDATE

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT UPDATE(DELETE_SESSION_ID) OR
   NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE i.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL)  -- early bail-out
    RETURN;

DELETE r
FROM REFRDEL r
JOIN inserted i ON r.PK1 = i.ACCT_ID
JOIN deleted d ON d.ACCT_ID = i.ACCT_ID  -- is this the primary key?
WHERE r.TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT'
  AND d.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NOT NULL
  AND i.DELETE_SESSION_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, funciona. Thanks.